# Is there a way to reference other parts of the command being entered in bash, similar to history expansion

Tags: bash, unix, zsh

I often need to refer to a piece of text in a bash command for example:

```
git mv _fav-locations-cluster.html.erb partials/_fav_locations_cluster.html.erb
```

**edit #1**

Note that it's going from dashes -> underscores

I'd like to do something like (where the $0 and tab would be eval'd or something):

```
git mv _fav-locations-cluster.html.erb partials/'$0 and tab'
```

where $0 and tab would reference the first argument. Is this possible in bash or zsh?

Comment: isn't it possible to simply do `git mv _fav-locations-cluster.html.erb partials/` ?

Comment: Actually changed from dashes to underscores so would need full piece

Comment: @timpone In which case, completion wouldn't be right either, as it would just reproduce the first argument and you'd have to go back to edit it anyway... I would just teach my fingers to `git mv _fav<tab> _fav<tab><edit to prepend path and correct name><enter>`...

Comment: it would potentially cut down on typing errors would be the big advantage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

History expansion can indeed refer to the line currently being typed:

```
$ git mv _fav-locations-cluster.html.erb partials/!#:2:gs/-/_/
```

`!#` refers to the current line. `:2` specifies the second word (the file name), and `:gs/-/_/` replaces all occurances of `-` with `_` in that word. After expansion, the command is

```
$ git mv _fav-locations-cluster.html.erb partials/_fav_locations_cluster.html.erb
```

Answer (score 2):

One simple trick is to stick the value in a variable and use that; this will work for your example above:

```
f=_fav-locations-cluster.html.erb; git mv "$f" partials/"${f//-/_}"
```

or create a function:

```
f() { git mv "$1" partials/"${1//-/_}".erb; }; f _fav-locations-cluster.html
```

Comment: thx for your opinion but none of your examples would work due to dashes -> underscores. I'm asking if there's a general purpose way to handle something like this NOT this exact case but this EXACT case was provided so that it isn't simply moving renaming a file.

Comment: cool, thx. looks nice. but no way to do it as an eval or something inline (sorry, really don't know - hence the question)? Seems like it'd be really powerful.

Comment: This is about as good as it gets on the same command line.  You do have lots of operators you can apply to history expansions to extract and modify values from previous commands, but not the current one - and semicolons don't split a line into multiple history entries.

Comment: @MarkReed you're forgetting the `!#` designator. See my answer.

Comment: @chepner - hm, I did indeed miss that.  OP should change the accepted answer to yours.

Comment: @chepner thx for posting chepner! never seen that before although I'm a total amateur on command line. amazing!

Answer (score 0):

In my `.zshrc` I have:

```
bindkey -M emacs "\M-;" copy-prev-word
```

This allows me to use <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> to copy the previous word. In your example that would copy `partials/` by default, but the widget also works with a numeric prefix to specify that an earlier word should be used. So using <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> before the `copy-prev-word` binding would accomplish what you're looking for.

Bash may have a similar command available.

Answer (score 0):

`git mv {,partials/}_fav-locations-cluster.html.erb`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to others solutions:

```
f=_fav-locations-cluster.html.erb; git mv $f partials/$f
```

The advantage of this solution is you can use $f in subsequent commands. The disadvantage is a) it takes two commands to accomplish the same task, and b) you got a residue variable $f afterward.

Comment: hmm... so needs to take into account that dashes -> underscores. Seems like not a quick way to do this. Agreed with your point about disadvantages.